# Drupal do not publish more current notes to other browsers than admin logs in

Tags: nodes

On my site eso-meetu.de Is a node created on  13 Juli, 2014  Drupal does not publish more current nodes to other browsers than the one i uuse to admister my site.

has someone any idea how to fix this or get closer to the error that populates this issue?

There are no errors in watchdog related to this also the server logs look fine

Even if I turn off memcache ore flush all caches the resul is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your site and all I see is "File not found.". If posts aren't showing up, check the view that is creating that list of content, it might be limited by a date range.